# email re-type alert jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

how to do a simple alert pop up with jquery, if the user didn't type the exact email address on the 2nd email input form? here's what i have so far

```
            <div id="reservation-request">

                <form method="post" action="test.php">
                    <tr>    
                        <td> Email</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td>re-type Email</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="Email2" id="Email2" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right">
                            <input type="image" src="images/submit.jpg">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a=$('#Email2').val();

var b=$('#Email1').val();
if(a!=b){
alert('email 1 and email 2 are different !')
};
```

Comment: how bout once the <input type="image" src="images/submi.jpg"> was clicked ?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this.

Give your submit button an id, like `submit`

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var e1 = $('#Email').val();
    var e2 = $('#Email2').val();

    if(e1 != e2){
       alert('Your emails don\'t match!!');
       return false
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/k4zwj/